# VSCode Rust debugging with lldb and cppvsdbg panics at "NotFound" message

Tags: debugging, rust, lldb, vscode-debugger, codelldb

Trying to debug my program written in rust with **lldb** and **cppvsdbg**, and after executing a function, that supposed to return either tuple of **Result(Protocol, Value)**, or **Box<dyn std::error::Error>** it throws this panic:

*thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." }', replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167:55*

I.e. it cannot find some file.

Not sure what file it refers to, but here is a full backtrace:

From lldb:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." }', replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167:55
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::dbghelp::trace
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\dbghelp.rs:98
   1:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\mod.rs:66    
   2:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:67
   3:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::{{impl}}::fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:46
   4:     0x7ff78323422b - core::fmt::write
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\fmt\mod.rs:1078
   5:     0x7ff783218ab8 - std::io::Write::write_fmt<std::sys::windows::stdio::Stderr>
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\io\mod.rs:1517
   6:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:49
   7:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::sys_common::backtrace::print
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:36
   8:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:208
   9:     0x7ff78321fa34 - std::panicking::default_hook
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:225
  10:     0x7ff7832208de - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:591
  11:     0x7ff783220401 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:497
  12:     0x7ff78321dbef - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace<closure-0,!>
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:141
  13:     0x7ff783220359 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:493
  14:     0x7ff783233550 - core::panicking::panic_fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:92
  15:     0x7ff783233373 - core::option::expect_none_failed
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\option.rs:1268
  16:     0x7ff782fd55e2 - core::result::Result<mpq::archive::Archive, std::io::error::Error>::unwrap<mpq::archive::Archive,std::io::error::Error>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\result.rs:973
  17:     0x7ff782fd4600 - replay_parser::parse_replay
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167
  18:     0x7ff782fd14d8 - sc2_emulator::main
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\sc2emul\src\main.rs:31
  19:     0x7ff782fd174b - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<fn() -> core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>,tuple<>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:227
  20:     0x7ff782fd154b - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace<fn() -> core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>,core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:125
  21:     0x7ff782fd17f1 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\rt.rs:66
  22:     0x7ff783220a94 - core::ops::function::impls::{{impl}}::call_once
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:280
  23:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::panicking::try::do_call
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:379
  24:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::panicking::try
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:343
  25:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::panic::catch_unwind
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panic.rs:396
  26:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::rt::lang_start_internal
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\rt.rs:51
  27:     0x7ff782fd17c3 - std::rt::lang_start<core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\rt.rs:65
  28:     0x7ff782fd1510 - main
  29:     0x7ff78325abbc - invoke_main
                               at d:\A01\_work\12\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  30:     0x7ff78325abbc - __scrt_common_main_seh
                               at d:\A01\_work\12\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
  31:     0x7ffed1de7034 - BaseThreadInitThunk
  32:     0x7ffed1f82651 - RtlUserThreadStart
```

And from cppvsdbg:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." }', replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167:55
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::dbghelp::trace
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\dbghelp.rs:98
   1:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\mod.rs:66    
   2:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:67
   3:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::{{impl}}::fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:46
   4:     0x7ff78323422b - core::fmt::write
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\fmt\mod.rs:1078
   5:     0x7ff783218ab8 - std::io::Write::write_fmt<std::sys::windows::stdio::Stderr>
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\io\mod.rs:1517
   6:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:49
   7:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::sys_common::backtrace::print
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:36
   8:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:208
   9:     0x7ff78321fa34 - std::panicking::default_hook
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:225
  10:     0x7ff7832208de - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:591
  11:     0x7ff783220401 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:497
  12:     0x7ff78321dbef - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace<closure-0,!>
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:141
  13:     0x7ff783220359 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:493
  14:     0x7ff783233550 - core::panicking::panic_fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:92
  15:     0x7ff783233373 - core::option::expect_none_failed
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\option.rs:1268
  16:     0x7ff782fd55e2 - core::result::Result<mpq::archive::Archive, std::io::error::Error>::unwrap<mpq::archive::Archive,std::io::error::Error>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\result.rs:973
  17:     0x7ff782fd4600 - replay_parser::parse_replay
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167
  18:     0x7ff782fd14d8 - sc2_emulator::main
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\sc2emul\src\main.rs:31
  19:     0x7ff782fd174b - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<fn() -> core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>,tuple<>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:227
  20:     0x7ff782fd154b - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace<fn() -> core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>,core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:125
  21:     0x7ff782fd17f1 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\rt.rs:66
  22:     0x7ff783220a94 - core::ops::function::impls::{{impl}}::call_once
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:280
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 3, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the path specified." }', replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167:55
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::dbghelp::trace
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\dbghelp.rs:98
   1:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\..\..\backtrace\src\backtrace\mod.rs:66    
   2:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:67
   3:     0x7ff78321d28e - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::{{impl}}::fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:46
   4:     0x7ff78323422b - core::fmt::write
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\fmt\mod.rs:1078
   5:     0x7ff783218ab8 - std::io::Write::write_fmt<std::sys::windows::stdio::Stderr>
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\io\mod.rs:1517
   6:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:49
   7:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::sys_common::backtrace::print
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:36
   8:     0x7ff78321ffcd - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:208
   9:     0x7ff78321fa34 - std::panicking::default_hook
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:225
  10:     0x7ff7832208de - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:591
  11:     0x7ff783220401 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:497
  12:     0x7ff78321dbef - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace<closure-0,!>
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:141
  13:     0x7ff783220359 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:493
  14:     0x7ff783233550 - core::panicking::panic_fmt
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:92
  15:     0x7ff783233373 - core::option::expect_none_failed
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\core\src\option.rs:1268
  16:     0x7ff782fd55e2 - core::result::Result<mpq::archive::Archive, std::io::error::Error>::unwrap<mpq::archive::Archive,std::io::error::Error>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\result.rs:973
  17:     0x7ff782fd4600 - replay_parser::parse_replay
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167
  18:     0x7ff782fd14d8 - sc2_emulator::main
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\sc2emul\src\main.rs:31
  19:     0x7ff782fd174b - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<fn() -> core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>,tuple<>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:227
  20:     0x7ff782fd154b - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace<fn() -> core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>,core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\sys_common\backtrace.rs:125
  21:     0x7ff782fd17f1 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}<core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\rt.rs:66
  22:     0x7ff783220a94 - core::ops::function::impls::{{impl}}::call_once
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:280
  23:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::panicking::try::do_call
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:379
  24:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::panicking::try
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:343
  25:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::panic::catch_unwind
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\panic.rs:396
  26:     0x7ff783220a94 - std::rt::lang_start_internal
                               at /rustc/cb75ad5db02783e8b0222fee363c5f63f7e2cf5b\/library\std\src\rt.rs:51
  27:     0x7ff782fd17c3 - std::rt::lang_start<core::result::Result<tuple<>, log::SetLoggerError>>
                               at C:\Users\Xeizzeth\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\std\src\rt.rs:65
  28:     0x7ff782fd1510 - main
  29:     0x7ff78325abbc - invoke_main
                               at d:\A01\_work\12\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:78
  30:     0x7ff78325abbc - __scrt_common_main_seh
                               at d:\A01\_work\12\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
  31:     0x7ffed1de7034 - BaseThreadInitThunk
  32:     0x7ffed1f82651 - RtlUserThreadStart
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this only happen during debugging? In any case the panic is produced in your code in:


17:     replay_parser::parse_replay
                               at D:\Projects\SC2Emul\SC2Emulator\replay_parser\src\lib.rs:167

Comment: Yes, it only happens during debugging. The program itself compiles and runs well.

Comment: And ok, I'll see to that line. I remember it yelling at .unwrap(), and indeed there is an unwrap on that line.

Comment: Hard to say what is going wrong without having a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I got it to work. It couldn't find the replay archive by relative path, so I had to supply the absolute path. Thank you for your help @HHK It was most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it couldn't find the replay archive specified. I supplied it with relative path, and during debugging it couldn't find it by relative path so I had to supply the absolute path.